# Responsive emails and AOL: My email appears as grey box

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, aol

I am making a HTML responsive email. It works fine in Gmail, Yahoo Mail, Outlook (online), icloud, Outlook (for Windows), Mail (for Mac) and Mail (for iOs).

However, in AOL Mail, it comes out as grey box. There's no text. Instead the contents are stipped out and replaced with:

```
<div class="aolReplacedBody" yahoo="fix" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important; background: #F0F0F0; color: #9a9a9a; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0.875rem; margin: 0; min-height: 1000px; min-width: 100% !important; padding: 0; width: 100% !important" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">

</div>
```

Why would this happen. Shouldn't at least some of my HTML remain in the email.

I have put my full code online [here](http://pastebin.com/GpUqPztS). However, I know that my code is quite dense (due to the nature of HTML emails) and might be difficult to look at. But I thought someone might have general experience as to why AOL displays on a grey box.

Comment: Contact AOL. Ask them.

Comment: @www139 They don't seem to have an email address for their webmail team.

Comment: I'm sorry. Good luck. Hope you solve the problem.